# Performance entre tipos de Update Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-update

Boa noite, preciso realizar um update em uma tabela 'a' nas linhas em que não existe uma ocorrência na tabela 'b', onde a tabela b tem cerca de 7 milhões de registros. 
Imaginei duas soluções porém não sei dizer qual seria a solução mais performática. Seguem :

Solução 1 :

```
update a 
left join b on a.coluna = b.id 
set a.coluna = null
where a.coluna is not null
and b.id is null ;
```

Solução 2 :

```
update a 
set a.coluna = null 
where a.coluna not in (select id from b);
```

Alguma ideia/sugestão?

Comment: Você também pode utilizar o `NOT EXISTS`: `UPDATE  a SET a.coluna = NULL WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM b WHERE a.coluna = b.id);`. Se existir um índice sobre a coluna b.id creio que a performance será melhor.

Comment: @anonimo obrigado. Em termos de performance a solução com o left join foi a melhor porém em algumas execuções gerou um deadlock. No fim, acabei optando pela alternativa com o 'not exists'